# Tengo esta actividad para desarrollar en Python, he intentado programarlo pero no se como continuar

Tags: python

EJERCICIO DE APLICACION (PROPUESTO)

realizar un programa que calcule la profundidad de una piscina de dimensiones NxM, para ello se utiliza una pelota. El programa debe mostrar el mayor valor de la celda y el camino de la pelota al rodar.

PASOS A SOLUCIONAR:
DATOS DE ENTRADA:
N = numero de filas

M = numero de columnas

profundidad = corresponde al valor(registro) enteros aleatorios

DATOS DE SALIDA:
P = mayor profundidad

camino = lista de valores

PROCEDIMIENTO:
Leer las dimensiones de la piscina "NxM". Crear la matriz "MP" llenar con valores aleatorios. Preguntar al usuario "la posicion inicial pelota, verificar que no sea borde y sea valida". Mientras encuentra la profundidad mayor: comparar: el valor de la celda con las filas y columnas adyacentes.Guarda la posicion.Seleccionar el valor mayor de las celdas adyacentes. Mostrar: profundidad mayor (P). Mostrar: camino (profundidades recorridas por la pelota).

```
   from random import *

      N = 7
      M = 11
      MP = [[randint(0,10) for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]

      for f in MP:
          print(f) 
      
      i=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada i de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))
      while i <=0 or i >=6:
            print ("Ha ingresado un valor invalido, por favor verifique que este no sea borde 
                    ni sobrepase la dimensión de la piscina")
      i=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada i de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))

      j=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada j de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))
      while j <=0 or j >=10:
      print ("Ha ingresado un valor invalido, por favor verifique que este no sea borde ni 
      sobrepase la dimensión de la piscina")
      j=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada j de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))

      print("La posición inicial de la pelota ingresada es: (",i,",",j,")")
```

Comment: Edita tu pregunta para agregar lo que mencionaste en tu comentario. También procura darle un título más específico: el actual es demasiado ambiguo.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Gracias por las recomendaciones

Comment: que se supone que hace el codigo?

Comment: Hola, es una matriz en este caso 7x11 la cual tiene valores aleatorios entre 0 y 10 en cada una de sus casillas, al usuario se le pide que introduzca la posicion inicial de la pelota (i,j) y se debe verificar que lo que ingrese sea valido, despues el programa se debe situar en esa casilla de posicion inicial y leer el valor que contenga digamos que sea un 2, luego se debe evaluar cada celda adyacente digamos que la fila es [1,2,5,8,4,..] entonces compara el 2 con el 5, el 5 con el 8 asi hasta encontrar la mayor...

Comment: he igual en la columna hasta que encuentre el valor mayor luego se debe imprimir este valor y mostrar en pantalla la ruta digamos que la ruta en el ejemplo seria 2,5,8 hasta que encontro el mayor

Comment: Porque sacaste el codigo? si sacas el codigo tengo que cerrar la pregunta porque es un ejercicio y aca no resolvemos ejercicios...

Comment: por que quitas el codigo?

Comment: @gbianchi calmate!,ahora lo revierto:/

Comment: @Christian en este caso, no reviertas.. mejor preguntar porque.. el codigo no aportaba mucho porque no hace nada...

Comment: @gbianchi a mi por lo menos me funcionó (pero no en la forma en que quiere), si crees que no aporta nada, en ese caso la pregunta se reduce a *hagan mi trabajo*, en ese caso debería ser cerrada

Comment: La identacion no es correcta. capaz lo hiciste andar, pero si ingresas la primer coordenada mal entra en un loop eterno... o me equivoco?

Answer (score 1):

Veamos:

```
from random import *

N = 7
M = 11
MP = [[randint(0,10) for j in range(M)] for i in range(N)]

for f in MP:
    print(f) 

i=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada i de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))
while i <=0 or i >=6:
    print ("Ha ingresado un valor invalido, por favor verifique que este no sea borde ni sobrepase la dimensión de la piscina")
    i=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada i de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))

j=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada j de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))
while j <=0 or j >=10:
    print ("Ha ingresado un valor invalido, por favor verifique que este no sea borde ni obrepase la dimensión de la piscina")
    j=int(input("Ingrese el valor de la coordenada j de la posicion inicial pelota:  "))

print("La posición inicial de la pelota ingresada es: (",i,",",j,")")
```

deberías revisar los condicionales en ambas coordenadas 0 es un valor válido ya que indica la fila.

Si tenes:

```
a=[[1,2,3],
[2,3,4]]
```

la coordenada 0 es = [1,2,3] salvo el 1 los otros son valores válidos

más allá de eso no has especificado si la solución tiene limitantes, así que te muestro como se podría hacer de una forma.

```
posicion = (i*M) + j
```

no quiero trabajar con la matriz, es más simple con una lista así que asigno a posición un valor dado por los datos ingresados, no creo tener que explicar una multiplicación y una suma.

```
inicio = [z  for x in MP for z in x ][posicion:]
```

ahora genero una lista plana de la matriz y le hago una tajada(slice) desde posición hasta el final de la matriz

```
final=inicio.index(max(inicio))
```

Ahora busco el valor máximo de la lista y obtengo su posición. ¿por qué uso max?. Es simple quizá elijan una posición donde ya no haya el valor máximo dado por randint o porque nunca uso el 10 como valor

```
camino = inicio[:final+1]
```

más de los mismo un slice desde el inicio hasta el valor máximo

```
print(camino)
```

Listo muestro el camino.

Un resultado posible:

```
[5, 0, 6, 1, 10, 8, 2, 7, 0, 9, 9]
[10, 7, 8, 3, 1, 6, 8, 0, 5, 3, 10]
[8, 7, 5, 5, 5, 7, 5, 6, 3, 3, 8]
[5, 2, 7, 6, 7, 0, 7, 8, 2, 10, 5]
[8, 7, 3, 1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 9, 6, 0]
[6, 0, 2, 0, 1, 3, 5, 7, 4, 3, 0]
[1, 1, 7, 5, 6, 1, 0, 4, 7, 4, 4]
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada i de la posicion inicial pelota:  0
Ha ingresado un valor invalido, por favor verifique que este no sea borde ni sobrepase la dimensión de la piscina
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada i de la posicion inicial pelota:  1
Ingrese el valor de la coordenada j de la posicion inicial pelota:  2
La posición inicial de la pelota ingresada es: ( 1 , 2 )
[8, 3, 1, 6, 8, 0, 5, 3, 10]
```